# " *int cannot be assigned to int " can someone explain pointers to me?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where I need to generate a random array of numbers and then reverse it in a second array. The problem is I don't quite understand how to use pointers or how to allocate memory for a dynamic array, as opposed to just setting constant values. Can anyone look at this code and see what I need to do to fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
int rows;
int columns;

printf("How many rows do you want?: ");
scanf_s("%i", &rows);
printf("\nHow many columns do you want?: ");
scanf_s("%i", &columns);
printf("\n");
//gets user input for how many rows and columns

int** mat = new int* [rows];
new int* [columns];

int i;
int j;

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        *mat[j] = mat[(rand() % 50) - 50];
        printf("%p", &mat[j]);
    }
}
}
```

The problem is in the for loop, I don't know how to go from mat* to mat.

Also no the program isn't fully complete, this is just an issue I keep running in to and need help for future reference.

Comment: Is this C or C++? I'm confused! It looks like you're mixing the two languages.

Comment: `new int* [columns];` doesn't do anything except leak memory. (And this is obviously C++, not C.)

Comment: For future reference, assuming you're working in C++, it's best practice to use a vector for variable sized  data.

Comment: Additionally, the size of an array in C++ must be a compile-time constant. VLAs are a C99 feature.

Comment: it is not clear why you prepend a `*` on `map[j]` but not on `mat[(rand() % 50) - 50]`. Why do you think you need to "go from mat* to mat" ?

Comment: @PranavVempati Where are you seeing a VLA?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow My mistake. I didn't see the dynamic allocation for some reason. Retracting my earlier comment.

Comment: @PranavVempati fwiw you don't have to "retract", you can delete it

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading some basic tutorials like the two listed below.

- Pointers(C/C++): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-c-examples/
- dynamic memory allocation(C++): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/new-and-delete-operators-in-cpp-for-dynamic-memory/

Comment: Thanks, my professor basically says "here's your homework good luck" and leaves it at that. Two weeks into school and he has already canceled half the classes but keeps giving work. Basically teaching myself lol, that's why the code is jut not good.